# problem to update a data in vb.net(for only one coulam in back end database)

Tags: vb.net

friends i has small probelm..

VB.NET i have only one colum in back end database that is roll. ..

Now i want to update a particular data ..

the data types is integer..

i has a data like 12 and i ant to update it 13 how can i do..
how can i do this
My code is---

```
    dim s1 as integer=TextBox1.Text
  str = "UPDATE  Table1 SET roll=" & TextBox1.Text & "  WHERE roll= " & s1 & " "
        cmd = New SqlCommand(str, cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are updating it with it's own value, I think textbox1.text in the SQL should be the modified text field?

Comment: or write str = "UPDATE  Table1 SET roll=" & (cint(TextBox1.Text) + 1) & "  WHERE roll= " & s1 & " ", if you want to add one